# How can I solve this git access rules: any one can create new branch, only admin can merge into "master"?

Tags: git, merge, branch, gitolite, repository

We are using git for our codes control, and I have some question on it.

I want this in a repo, using git it self or tools such as "gitolite":

1. only specified persion can merge code to specified branch.
2. somebody( such as a group called "admin") can create new branch,
   and have full permission "RW+", maybe all development group member
   should have this access permission
3. all persion can create new branch with a specified prefix, such as a prefix called "bug", will allow all persion create branches
   called bug001, bug123...

I don't know if I missunderstanded the usage of "git", or maybe I should actualize this access rules via "repo", not branch?

Look forward to someone can answer my question eagerly, any solution will be ok, such as gitolite, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for only Admin can merge will be accomplished by MERGE-CHECK VREF 
https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/VREF/MERGE-CHECK

For Only some one can create a branch - any one can create a branch, but can or Cannot Push, Overwrite, Delete depending upon RWCD configuration. Again you can get it at http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html